# time.sleep requires integers?

Tags: python, time, integer, sleep, pyhook

I'm writing a macro that will click certain spots on the screen when I press a key.

The first time I press a key, everything runs fine.
However, any other key press results in the error:

```
    time.sleep(0.1)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is the code:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time
import pythoncom
import pyHook
import os

def Click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

def DeleteRun(event):
    Click(1250, 741)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Click(649,261)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Click(651, 348)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Click(800, 442)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Click(865, 612)


Click(20,20)
KeyGrabber = pyHook.HookManager()
KeyGrabber.KeyDown = DeleteRun
KeyGrabber.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

It seems the first time the `DeleteRun` function is run by `pyHook`, `time.sleep(`) accepts floats.
On any following function calls, it seems it only accepts integers.

What is causing this?
I can't wait 5 seconds for the mouse arrangement! It's supposed to save time!

**Specs:**

- python 2.7.2
- Windows 7 (32)

Comment: Can you do `import time as time_safe` and use `time_safe` in place of `time`? Maybe pyHook is doing something with the `time` class.

Comment: No success I'm afraid. I've noticed however that it alternates working and failing.

Comment: Maybe try specifically `from time import sleep`?

Comment: try: `import time, functools` before any other module and use `Sleep = functools.partial(time.sleep, 0.1)` and later in the `DeleteRun(event): ... Sleep() ...`

Comment: Both of these: no luck.
"    sleep()
TypeError: an integer is required"

Comment: Where in your stack are you explicitly getting this error? It's possible that you're being thrown by the invocation of `time.sleep` in a different portion of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, how about this?  Add a return True to DeleteRun:

```
def DeleteRun(event):
    Click(1250, 741)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    [...]
    return True
```

I should probably confess that this was little more than google-fu: read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049068/help-with-pyhook-error).

Comment: Having another issue, perhaps related.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763053/pyhook-giving-up

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what's wrong with Windows this time, but you could try faking a high-precision sleep using select() with no file descriptors.

Comment: Could you give me an example of implementation?