# time.sleep (got type NoneType)

Tags: python, pyhook

So I have been working on a very basic 'fastclick macro'. I want the program to click more if I click faster than around 5 clicks per second. When it reaches the limit of 5 clicks per second, i want it to click in between your last and your next click, done with the `time.sleep(clicktime / 2)`. For some reason, i get an error:

> an integer is required (got type NoneType)

here is my code:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, sys, winsound, os
import win32api, win32con, random, time
from pyHook import HookManager
from pyHook.HookManager import HookConstants

macro = False
tip = 1
firstclick = 0
secondclick = 0
clicktime = 1

bot = False

def ExtraClick():
    global clicktime
    global bot
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    print('click')
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0) 
    bot = True  

def OnMouseClick(event):
    global tip
    global firstclick
    global secondclick
    global clicktime
    global macro
    global bot

    if bot == True:
        bot = False

    if bot == False:
        if tip == 0:
            tip = 1
            firstclick = time.time()
            clicktime = firstclick - secondclick
            print(clicktime)


        elif tip == 1:
            tip = 0
            secondclick = time.time()
            clicktime = secondclick - firstclick
            print(clicktime)                    


def OnKeyEvent(event):
    global macro
    if event.KeyID == 192:
        if macro == True:
            macro = False
            print('off')
            winsound.Beep(600, 30)
            winsound.Beep(550, 30)
        else:
            macro = True
            print('on')
            winsound.Beep(1000, 30)
            winsound.Beep(1100, 30)
            clickspeed = 1

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
while True:
    hm.MouseLeftDown = OnMouseClick
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyEvent    
    if clicktime < 0.20 and macro == True:
        time.sleep(clicktime / 2)
        ExtraClick()      
    hm.HookMouse()
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

i also tried to, instead of using `time.sleep(clicktime / 2)`, `time.sleep(0.1)`, but that gave the same error.

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: Like @zondo said you should post the error trackback (or the most important parts of it). That would show the file and the line in that file that raised this error. I suspect the error file/line was not where your time.sleep() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with time.sleep but rather with pyhook - it appears it requires that handlers return a value (True or False).

See this answer: [Help with pyHook error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049068/help-with-pyhook-error)

Add `return True` to the end of event handlers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got mislead towards the time.sleep.